# multiple excel OR conditions

Tags: excel, multiple-conditions

Request help:

```
=IF(AND(OR(
          S:S="Sales Hub",
          S:S="Office Integration",
          S:S="Opportunities",
          S:S="Export to Excel",
          S:S="Gamification",
          S:S="LinkedIn",
          S:S="Leads")),
    "Project One",
    IF(AND(OR(
             S:S="Invoices",
             S:S="Products and Pricelists",
             S:S="Quotes and Orders")),
       "Project Two",
       IF(AND(OR(
                S:S="Quick Campaigns",
                S:S="Marketing Lists")),
           "Project Three",
           ""
       )
    )
 )
```

The above formula returns only Project One for all even though i have matching values to meet Project Two and Three as specified in the nested OR conditions.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to debug an if/or statement is to highlight part of the formula in the formula bar, then hit f9 and see what it evaluates to.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use whole column references with this kind of formula. Can you explain what you would like to achieve? I think you may be using the wrong formula. Edit your question, post a small data sample and the expected outcome, so we can see what we're aiming for. Again, edit the question. Don't put that into a comment.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  As @teylyn says, your conditions are basically “if column S contains Sales Hub or Office Integration or ...., then Project One”.   That other matching values exist in the column is irrelevant if column S contains at least one value for Project One.   Also, the calls to AND are redundant since you’re only ever giving it a single value.

Comment: i have skill sets in column A and want to group them under three project viz. Project One to Three and display the Project wise count in another column

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to check if any of the specified values is present on column S and if true, then return Project #.

You can do it combining COUNTIF with array criteria and SUM. If it's greater than 0, it means the condition has been met.

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(S:S;{"Sales Hub";"Office Integration";"Opportunities";"Export to Excel";"Gamification";"LinkedIn";"Leads"}))>0;"Project One";IF(SUM(COUNTIF(S:S;{"Invoices";"Products and Pricelists";"Quotes and Orders"}))>0;"Project Two";IF(SUM(COUNTIF(S:S;{"Quick Campaigns";"Marketing Lists"}))>0;"Project Three";"Error")))
```

Comment: it didn't work, when i pasted your countif in the new col it results only Project One

Comment: Are you sure there are conditions for the other 2 projects? Can you upload your data?

Comment: Issue got resolved and below is what i used:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sales",        B3,1)),"Sales",
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Arch",         B3,1)),"Architecture",
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Land",         B3,1)),"Land",
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("All",          B3,1)),"All",
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Contracts",    B3,1)),"Contracts",
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Construction", B3,1)),"Construction",
 "No Match"
 ))))))